# Simple main effects - R

Tags: r, anova, interaction

This is a simple question yet I cannot find a definitive answer anywhere. When running a two-way anova in R, I get a significant interaction. I am aware that because the interaction effect was significant, we would like to compare all group means from the interaction.  Even though the main effects were significant, the typical advice is to not conduct pairwise comparisons for main effects when their interaction is significant.  This is because focusing on the groups in the interaction better describe the results of the analysis (taken from [here](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/G_09.html)). So now I know that we have to use some part of the full, two-way anova (the MS error? The MS residual?) and include it in separate one-way anovas on each level in the dataset. 
Can someone please describe how to do this in base R in a step-by-step manner? I realise there are packages available for this (e.g. `lsmeans` and `emmeans`), but I am wary of using them without first understanding what exactly is going on and why.

Here is an example of a significant interaction in R using `iris`:

```
summary(aov(iris$Petal.Length~iris$Sepal.Length*iris$Sepal.Width))
                                    Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)    
iris$Sepal.Length                    1  352.9   352.9 889.706 < 2e-16 ***
iris$Sepal.Width                     1   50.0    50.0 126.125 < 2e-16 ***
iris$Sepal.Length:iris$Sepal.Width   1    3.5     3.5   8.905 0.00334 ** 
Residuals                          146   57.9     0.4                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Thank you

Comment: Your independent variables are continuous. There are no groups. You are conducting a regression analysis. Check out `summary(fit <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length * Sepal.Width, data = iris)); anova(fit)`.

Comment: There are a number of vignettes with the **emmeans** package that attempt to explain “what is going on and why.” I suggest starting with the “basics” one.